I am getting an Error while renaming directory which i was using to create an app using command npm run reset-project EPERM operation not permitted
I am using Expo for starting my app on my Android device  and in the index.tsx file it is written
that use npm run reset-project for making a fresh project
but I am getting an error:
Error renaming directory: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, 
rename 'D:\Deliver-App\delivero\app' -> 'D:\Deliver-App\delivero\app-example'

I tried to find the solution to the problem, which is to disable the read-only property in package.json file

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Make sure Expo server is not running or press Ctrl + C if it is running.
Then try again execute command npm run reset-project

If someone is facing the same problem, you will have to make sure that the React Native app is not running in background, and what you can do is just restart your desktop to get it working, if not even after closing the app on the local server.
To close the running service

ctrl + c

To reset the dir

npm run reset-project


And even if all of this does not work, just create a new React Native app!
